# Grab username:password from text file, then post into login form

Tags: python, file

I have a text file with usernames and passwords. The text file is formatted like this:

```
username1:password1
username2:password2
username3:password3
```

I want to grab the first line, split it to "username1" and "password1", and then post to this:

```
br.form['login'] = 'username1'
br.form['passwd'] = 'password1'
```

After that, I want it to repeat and move onto username2:password2.

How can this be done?

Comment: That sounds... sketchy.

Comment: What's br.form?  is it a dict?

Comment: I apologize Borealid, I've tried a lot of different code with no luck. And the br.form is from mechanize. :)

Comment: @Shtoops: Post the code you tried here. It will help us help you.

Comment: You should store all password encrypted, not as plain text. The best algorithm to use is probably bcrypt: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming no `:` characters in your usernames or passwords:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    credentials = [x.strip().split(':', 1) for x in f]

for username, password in credentials:
    # your code here
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much! I don't quite understand how the credentials string works, but I'll make sure to research it so I don't have to ask again. ;)

Comment: @Shtoops: `credentials` is not a string, it is a `list` consisting of two elements: first is the part of the line before "`:`" and the second is the part of the line after it.

Comment: Actually it is a list of lists, and we don't know how many elements (depends on `myfile.txt` contents).

Answer (score 5):

1) read the file line by line
  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

2) split the line (string)
  http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

3) post the information
  http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Use google to help figure out each step.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename=<path to file>
separator=":"
fileIN = open(filename, "r")
line = fileIN.readline()

while line:
    sout=line.split(separator)
    user=sout[0]
    passwd=sout[1]
    ..... do your stuff......
    line = fileIN.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect usecase of `requests`, requests has built-in [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#basic-authentication).